# (1/1) Exception Property [price] does not exist on this collection instance. (Laravel 5.4)

Tags: php, laravel, shopping-cart

I have this function on Cart Model

```
//Cart.php

<?php

namespace App;


class Cart
{
    public $items= null;
    public $totalQty=0;
    public $totalPrice=0;
    public function __construct($oldCart){
        if($oldCart){
            $this->items= $oldCart->items;
            $this->totalQty= $oldCart->totalQty;
            $this->totalPrice= $oldCart->totalPrice;


        } 
    }


 public function addCart($item, $id){

      $storedItem=['qty'=>0, 'item'=>$item, 'price'=>$item->price];
        if($this->items){
            if(array_key_exists($id, $this->items)){
                $storedItem= $this->items[$id];
            }
        }
        $storedItem['qty']++;
        $storedItem['price'] *= $storedItem['qty'];
        $this->items[$id]= $storedItem;
        $this->totalQty++;
        $this->totalPrice +=$storedItem['price'];
   }


}
```

and this is my function on my controller

```
public function addToCart(Request $request, $id){
    $pork=Pork::where('did', $id)->get();
    $oldCart=Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
    $cart= new Cart($oldCart);
    $cart->addCart($pork, $id);
  $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);

 return redirect()->route('user.index', compact('pork'));

}
```

I am trying to get the price so I could calculate it. The code is working well, but when i tried adding 'price'=>$item->price on the storedItem array. It is giving error which is 
(1/1) Exception Property [price] does not exist on this collection instance. (Laravel 5.4)

```
$storedItem=['qty'=>0, 'item'=>$item, 'price'=>$item->price];
```

could anyone help me? what should i do with this?

here is my blade view

```
@if(isset(Session::get('cart')->items))
@foreach(Session::get('cart')->items as $crt)
@foreach($crt['item'] as $pork)
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <div id="cartdiv">  
              <dt>
               <div>
                 <input type="number" min="1" value="{{$crt['qty']}}">

               </dt>
              <dd>
                <label>
                <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{$pork['pork_name']}}</b>
                </label>
               </dd>
                 <dt>
                <label"> Price: <b id="bprice"  name="price">{{$pork['basePrice']}}</b></label>
                </dt>
                 <dd>
                <label>Total Amount: 200.00</label>
                </dd>
              </dt>
          </div>
      </dl>
@endforeach
@endforeach
 @endif
```

Answer (score 1):

`get()` will return a collection even if only 1 result found, you can use `first()` to get the first result.

Just change 
`$pork=Pork::where('did', $id)->get();` to `$pork=Pork::where('did', $id)->first();`

view file should changed to

```
@if(isset(Session::get('cart')->items))
@foreach(Session::get('cart')->items as $crt)
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <div id="cartdiv">  
              <dt>
               <div>
                 <input type="number" min="1" value="{{$crt['qty']}}">

               </dt>
              <dd>
                <label>
                <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{$crt['item']->name}}</b>
                </label>
               </dd>
                 <dt>
                <label"> Price: <b id="bprice"  name="price">{{$crt['item']->price}}</b></label>
                </dt>
                 <dd>
                <label>Total Amount: 200.00</label>
                </dd>
              </dt>
          </div>
      </dl>
@endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: I tried the first() but it is not showing the pork's name

Comment: @naning14 what do you mean by it's not showing the pork's name? did $pork get an instance of Pork model using first()?

Comment: I needed to display pork's name in my blade but when i tried the first() instead of get() it is not showing its name

Comment: @naning14 paste your blade file here too, let's see what's the issue there

Comment: I actually do not have problem in getting Pork and its data. It works really well. My main problem is here: 
$storedItem=['qty'=>0, 'item'=>$item, 'price'=>$item->price];

so when i tried adding 'price->$item->price on that array it is giving me this error
 (1/1) Exception Property [price] does not exist on this collection instance.

But thank you, I learned something.

Comment: @naning14 I understand you, but to fix that problem, we need change get() to first(), and it seems that cause your blade view not working, so we need fix blade view too, so i guess your old code in blade need change, that's why I asked you to paste that code into question too.

Comment: Okay 
here's my blade view

Comment: how do you put code on comment. I am a new user here :)

Comment: @naning14 you can edit your question, just add to the bottom, if your code is long, it's hard to put into comment.

Comment: you can try $pork->pork_name instead of $pork['pork_name']

Comment: not working. There's an error saying "Trying to get property of non-object " at that line

Comment: update my answer, i don't know what's your db structure of that table, but basically you just need remove the inner loop and access $ctr['item'] directly

Answer (score 1):

As @wanghanlin has stated - you need to pick the `first` record from the `collection` - also `Session::get()` has second argument, which by default is `null` so you could refactor as:

```
public function addToCart(Request $request, $id)
{

    $pork = Pork::where('did', $id)->get()->first() ?? new Pork;
    $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    $cart->addCart($pork, $id);
    $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);

    return redirect()->route('user.index', compact('pork'));

}
```

Comment: It is not displaying the pork's name too

Comment: If there aren't any records available then `first()` method will return `null`, hence I've instantiated `new Port` for that scenario so at least you have an instance of the desired model. What you should then do is perhaps check if Pork actually exists `if ($pork->exists)` - this will tell you if at least one record matching the `where` clause was found. Missing `name` - I could only imagine that it's either not associated with the existing record or you have an empty `Pork` model instance because there were no records matching your `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(isset(Session::get('cart')->items))
@foreach(Session::get('cart')->items as $crt)
@foreach($crt['item'] as $pork)
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <div id="cartdiv">  
              <dt>
               <div>
                 <input type="number" min="1" value="{{$crt['qty']}}">

               </dt>
              <dd>
                <label>
                <b>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{$pork['pork_name']}}</b>
                </label>
               </dd>
                 <dt>
                <label"> Price: <b id="bprice"  name="price">{{$pork['basePrice']}}</b></label>
                </dt>
                 <dd>
                <label>Total Amount: 200.00</label>
                </dd>
              </dt>
          </div>
      </dl>
@endforeach
@endforeach
 @endif
```

That's my blade view

Comment: you can try $pork->pork_name instead of $pork['pork_name'], same on price